# Angular.js $http.get method works well with IE10 and IE11 but not IE9

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer

So I'm working on an angular.js app which works fine with the recent versions of IE like IE10 and IE11 but not IE9. Here is what my javascript service request code looks like:

```
$http({method: 'GET',url: s_url})
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {......
```

Is there Something I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post all code for service?

Comment: @Phix The status displays as undefined. The rest of the service code is manipulation of the data.

Comment: Any chance you try to access a service using CORS ? IE9 only partially support it, see http://caniuse.com/#feat=cors

Comment: Is there any data associated with the http call in the dev tools? In other words, is the http call performing at all? Headers etc

Comment: @Phix No, headers comes back as undefined as well.